# Blocked communication with API under windows 7 but not windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, api, rad-studio

I created a 32 bit program with Rad studio 10.4 in C++. This program must communicate with 2 APIs.

My development machine is running Windows 10 x64 and all tests are going well. The program communicates perfectly with APIs.

I put the program in production at my client, on a Windows 7 x64 machine and there, the communication is not done, return code 0.

I test on a new VM in Windows 7 x64 and the problem is the same.

I'm testing on a new VM in Windows 10 x64 and no worries, communication is fine.

I of course disabled the firewall, also added rules in the firewall but nothing changes.

Do you have any idea where the problem could come from ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Firewall? So you are using sockets? Post some code or any kind of detailed information...

Answer (score 0):

```
this->RESTClient_maj->BaseURL = "urlapi";
this->RESTRequest_maj->Params->Items[0]->Value = "token 1234";
this->RESTRequest_maj->Execute();
```

I use components from Rad Studio and get and patch methods.

what additional information can I provide ?